# Determine the area of the region enclosed by $x$ and $y$?

Tags: calculus, integration, curves

$$x= \left(\frac{1}{2} y\right)^2 - 3$$

$$Y= x-1 $$

All examples I viewed online seem to have no $x$ in them, should I write the equation in terms of $Y$? Would doing this give me $Y=x-1$  and  $y= \left(\frac{1}{2}x\right)^2$.  (Nearly $100 \%$ sure that's wrong.)

I can't get to the integration bits without understanding the question first, any tips please?

Comment: _What helps in nearly any integration question like this :_ Write out both functions with respect to the same variable, find the points of intersection (useful for bounds), and try to make a rough sketch of what your area looks like.

Comment: What is the difference between Y and y?

Comment: Ahhh my suggested edit may be incorrect if there is a difference between Y and y, I just assumed it was poorly typed. If so, my apologies!

Answer (score 1):

To find the area bounded by the curves 
in this case is easier to consider an equivalent system of
the two functions

\begin{align}
f_1(y)&= \left(\frac{1}{2} y\right)^2 - 3
\\
f_2(y)&=y+1,
\end{align}

or, to make it look more familiar,

\begin{align}
f_1(x)&= \left(\frac{1}{2} x\right)^2 - 3
\\
f_2(x)&=x+1,
\end{align}
since $y$ or $x$ is just the name of parameter,
which we are free to choose suitable.

Next you need to find the points of intersection,
when $f_1(x)=f_2(x)$ which is this simple case are 
the limits of integration $a=2-2\sqrt5$, $b=2+2\sqrt5$.

[image]

The area then is just

\begin{align}
S&=\int_a^b f_2(x)-f_1(x) dx.
\end{align}